# Cannot access 'y' before initialization javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I am trying to swap values of two variables using array destructuring, however I get the error `Cannot access 'y' before initialization`. Can someone please explain why it is not working and provide a solution

my code :

```js
    let x = 'bob'
    let y = 'john'
    
    [x, y]=[y, x]
    
    console.log(x, y)
```

error: `Cannot access 'y' before initialization`

Comment: It is working as expected, Doesn't give me an error... [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/MWoYywL?editors=0011)

Comment: Use semicolons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) Also: [a javascript question about destructuring when `[a, b] = [b ,a]`](/q/56204661/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

semicolons are missing

```
let x = 'bob';
let y = 'john';

[x, y]=[y, x];

console.log(x, y)
```